# Why did you sql query overcome hibernate query?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to know *difference* between **Mysql Query** and **Hibernate Query**. Anybody know give your Suggestion

Comment: Please do a google search. This two topics are very broad and different.One of the common thing is that they help us to getting data from database

Answer (score 1):

There is a world of difference between the two. I will try my best to explain it to you.

For writing a MySQL query, you need to think in terms of tables, whereas for a Hibernate query, you need to think in terms of objects.

If you have MySQL queries embedded in your Java code, when you try to switch your database to a different one (say Oracle for example), your queries may not work anymore. This is because different db vendors have different syntax's that they need you to use to accomplish the same goal.

However, in the case of a Hibernate query, you will need to just change the appropriate property in the hibernate configuration file. Since you write queries in terms of objects, Hibernate will automatically generate the appropriate SQL it requires to work with the underlying db.

Also, one another major difference between the two (or between Hibernate and a specific db query language) is the way joins are done. We can use the dot operator in Hibernate Query Language (HQL) to access the properties of a component object without needing to explicitly specify a JOIN clause as we would in a specific query language.

Besides this, there are tons of differences between the two and in no way can all of them be summarized here.